# BIRT 4.8 Overlapping issue

Tags: birt

[Has anyone done something like this in BIRT 4.8. I am trying to generate data that will overlap to the next page. Before the data overlaps, it generates the total amount of the data for that page. When it gets to the second page, it generates the total data in that page. The final total will appear at the end of the page. There will a check that will be a footer and the goal is to put that on the first page only and same with the data on the header. After the sublines are completed, we generate a new check.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw4FJ.png)

Comment: If you want a page total, then you probably need page variables and use separate `RunTask` and `RenderTask`. I've never done this, but I assume it should be possible with this approach. Not sure what you mean with "check" here, though.

Comment: the check will be in the footer section for only the first page.

Comment: I didn't ask *where* the "check" is, I want to know what you mean with it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a footer displayed on page 1 only and at the same time have the table start on page 1 and continue on page 2.

For different footers, you need different master pages.

But a single layout element (e.g. your table) cannot span different master pages; if a layout element specifies a master page and this differs from the current master page, there will be a page break before the layout element.